# Authenticated navigation in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I am learning React. My React router code is like below

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
        <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" exact component={Dashboard} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
```

My private route is like below

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component }) => (
    <Route
        render={props =>
            (Auth.isAuthenticated() ? ( <Component {...props} />) : (<Redirect to={{ pathname: '/',}}/>))
        }
    />
);
```

Using above code I can browse login page after login (http://localhost:3000/). But after successful login  I need to redirect to `dashboard`page if anyone try to browse login page.

How can I do it ?

Comment: In `Login Component`, you should check `Auth.isAuthenticated()`: if `true` then Redirect to `/dashboard`

Comment: Thanks @RyanNghiem. Is it possible to check in Router ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a visitor-only route similar to a private route. If user is authenticated redirect to dashboard, else render target component.

```
const VisitorOnlyRoute = ({ component: Component }) => (
    <Route
        render={props =>
            (Auth.isAuthenticated() === false? ( <Component {...props} />) : (<Redirect to={{ pathname: '/dashboard',}}/>))
        }
    />
);
```

Now use this route component with your login/register components like this:

```
<VisitorOnlyRoute path="/register" exact component={Register} />
```

Comment: Thanks @Mezba for your solution. Your solution is working.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the `Route` component your `Login` component is getting the `history` prop with which you can initiate a redirect.

Just call `history.push('/dashboard')` after your login was succesful.

```
/* In your `Login` component */
function doLogin() {
    somehowSendLoginApiRequest().((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
            this.props.history.push('/dashboard');
        }
    });
}
```